# Polygon movement towards a point

Tags: android, libgdx, collision-detection, polygon

I recently started using the Polygons but I'm have struggle as I'm trying to make a Polygon move towards the center of my screen, although I don't know how.
Here's the code I have(**What I'm trying to accomplish here is to make the balls spawn randomly by every side of the screen and make them go towards the middle of the screen to collide against a square**):

```
public class Game extends com.badlogic.gdx.Game implements Screen{

private SpriteBatch batch;
private Texture Ball;
private Texture Up;
private OrthographicCamera cam;
private int score;
private String showScore;
private BitmapFont scoreFont;
private Sprite upSprite;

private Polygon square;

private Array<Polygon> balls1;
private Array<Polygon> balls2;
private Array<Polygon> balls3;
private Array<Polygon> balls4;

private Polygon ball1 = new Polygon();
private Polygon ball2 = new Polygon();
private Polygon ball3 = new Polygon();
private Polygon ball4 = new Polygon();

@Override
public void create(){

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Ball = new Texture("energyball.png");
    Up = new Texture("up.png");

    upSprite = new Sprite(Up);

    upSprite.setOriginCenter();
    upSprite.setX(615);
    upSprite.setY(340);
    upSprite.setRegionWidth(64);
    upSprite.setRegionHeight(64);

    square = new Polygon(new float[] {
            upSprite.getX(), upSprite.getY(),
            upSprite.getX(), upSprite.getY() + upSprite.getHeight(),
            upSprite.getX() + upSprite.getWidth(), upSprite.getY() + upSprite.getY(),
            upSprite.getX() + upSprite.getWidth(), upSprite.getY()
    });

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, 1280, 720);

    upSprite.setPosition(upSprite.getX(), upSprite.getY());

    square.setOrigin(upSprite.getX(), upSprite.getY());

    // calls the functions to spawn balls randomly
    balls1 = new Array<Polygon>();

    balls2 = new Array<Polygon>();

    balls3 = new Array<Polygon>();

    balls4 = new Array<Polygon>();

    score();


    //if the screen is touched sprite rotates 90 degrees clockwise
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter() {

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {

            upSprite.rotate(-90);
            square.rotate(-90f);
            return true;
        }
    });


}


//shows score
private void score() {

    score = -4;
    showScore = "Score: 0";
    scoreFont = new BitmapFont();

}


//creates the balls and sets their position as well as the random timer for each
private void spawnBalls1() {

    ball1.setPosition(MathUtils.random(639, 641), 720);
    ball1.setScale(32, 32);
    balls1.add(ball1);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

}

private void spawnBalls2() {

    ball2.setPosition(0, MathUtils.random(359, 361));
    ball2.setScale(32, 32);
    balls2.add(ball2);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

private void spawnBalls3() {

    ball3.setPosition(MathUtils.random(639, 641), 0);
    ball3.setScale(32, 32);
    balls3.add(ball3);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

private void spawnBalls4() {

    ball4.setPosition(1280, MathUtils.random(359, 361));
    ball4.setScale(32, 32);
    balls4.add(ball4);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}

@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    cam.update();

    //draws the game itself as well as the balls on the screen
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();

    upSprite.draw(batch);

    //draws the balls
    for (Polygon ball1 : balls1) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball1.getX(), ball1.getY());
    }

    for (Polygon ball2 : balls2) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball2.getX(), ball2.getY());
    }

    for (Polygon ball3 : balls3) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball3.getX(), ball3.getY());
    }

    for (Polygon ball4 : balls4) {

        batch.draw(Ball, ball4.getX(), ball4.getY());
    }

    scoreFont.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    scoreFont.draw(batch, showScore, 25, 100);

    batch.end();

    // if the time minus the time of the last ball spawn is less than x then spawn another ball in a random place
        if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) {

            switch (MathUtils.random(4)) {

                case 0:
                    spawnBalls1();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    spawnBalls2();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    spawnBalls3();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    spawnBalls4();
                    break;
            }
        }
    Iterator<Polygon> iter1 = balls1.iterator();
    while(iter1.hasNext()) {

        Polygon balls1 = iter1.next();
        balls1.getY() -= 350 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(balls1, square)) {

            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter1.remove();
        }

    }

    Iterator<Polygon> iter2 = balls2.iterator();
    while (iter2.hasNext()) {

        Polygon balls2 = iter2.next();
        balls2.x += 550 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(balls2, square)) {
            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter2.remove();
        }

    }


    Iterator<Polygon> iter3 = balls3.iterator();
    while(iter3.hasNext()) {

        Polygon balls3 = iter3.next();
        balls3.y += 350 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(balls3, square)) {

            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter3.remove();
        }
    }

    Iterator<Polygon> iter4 = balls4.iterator();
    while(iter4.hasNext()) {

        Polygon balls4 = iter4.next();
        balls4.x -= 550 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Intersector.overlapConvexPolygons(balls4, square)) {

            score++;
            showScore = "Score: " + score;
            iter4.remove();
        }

    }

}
```

And I'm getting an error here:

```
balls1.getY() -= 350 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

balls2.getX() += 550 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

balls3.getY() += 350 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

balls4.getX() -= 550 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: The errors you get should be self-explanatory. `balls1.getY() -= ...` is trying to change a temporary variable that you get from `getY()`. To really change the y value you probably want `balls1.y -= ...` or `balls1.setY(...)`

Comment: i cant do `balls1.setY()` and `balls1.y` doesnt work

Comment: `balls1.setPosition()` ? Go to the `Polygon` class documentation and find the methods that may help you.